# Map array structure in php

Tags: php

I need to find a nice solution to map one database model to another, third party model.

The code currently has to do something like:

```
'HomePhone' => $customer['details']['phone']['home']
```

for example.

As you can imagine, if `$customer['details']['phone']['home']` is used multiple times, it becomes a nightmare to modify the keys if the database changes (as it does).

So I would like to have a config to use for the mapping, for example

```
$map = [
    'HomePhone' => 'customer.details.phone.home'
]
```

Such that, I can simple use `$map['HomePhone']` throughout, and only need to change the one spot for the data model, eg to change it to `customer.details.homephone`

If this is the structure of the config item, how would I take `customer.details.phone.home` and explode it to `[customer][details][phone][home]` within the assignment above ?

Is this thinking valid, or is there a better way ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### welcome to data abstraction

Generally speaking, if you have some datum and you want to get a specifc piece of data *out*, you write a *selector*. The good news is, you're on the right path – only you're just trying to solve it a little incorrectly …

```
// some data
$customer = [
  // ...
  'details' => [
    // ...
    'phone' => [
      // ...
      'home' => '0123456789'
    ]
  ]
];

// a selector
function customerHomePhone($customer) {
  return $customer['details']['phone']['home'];
}
```

Now whenever you need to access this property in your code, you will always do so using

```
<span>Home Phone: <?php echo customerHomePhone($customer) ?></span>
```

---

The benefits of this are absolutely tremendous.

The person trying to get data from `$customer` doesn't need to know anything about *how* it's structured.

What if the data were to become extremely complex, with hundreds of fields and dozens of levels of nesting? It might be really frustrating to have to look at a reference object to re-learn how to access a field you need to read.

I can always remember `customerHomePhone($customer)` but it's much harder to remember …

```
$customer['details']['phone']['home']
```

*"Was it `detail` singular or `details` plural? Wait, yeah, I think `phones` was pluralized but `detail` was singular... dammit !"*

---

What it also means is that you have **freedom to change** where the home phone data (or any data) is stored – change it *however* you want – and all you have to do is update it *one* place in your app.

Say you change it to be stored as …

```
$customer['contacts']['home_phone']
```

… all you have to do is update `customerHomePhone` to …

```
function customerHomePhone($customer) {
  return $customer['contacts']['home_phone'];
}
```

Or `$customer` might even change more significantly. Maybe you'll use `stdClass` instead of array so the selector becomes …

```
function customerHomePhone($customer) {
  return $customer->details->phone->home;
}
```

It doesn't matter. As long as the *selector* points to the correct value in whatever data structure you're using, the rest of your app is shielded from the change and continues to work perfectly.

---

Of course it would make sense to build other selectors as well …

```
function customerDetails($customer)
  return $customer['details'];
}

function customerPhones($customer) {
  return customerDetails($customer)['phone'];
}

function customerHomePhone($customer) {
  return customerPhones($customer)['home'];
}
```

---

Would you like to learn more about data abstraction? Check out these links:

- https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_sec_2.1
- http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/2b-compound-data/
- http://www.sicpdistilled.com/section/2-data-abstraction/

---

#### OOP

Maybe you don't like the functional approach, or maybe OOP gels better with your existing app. `class`es are OOP's golden hammer when it comes to data abstraction – or any abstraction for that matter.

```
class Customer {
  private $data;
  public function __construct(array $data) {
    $this->data = $data;
  }
  // maybe we only use details internally, thus private
  private function details() {
    return $this->data['details'];
  }
  public function first_name() {
    return $this->details()['first_name'];
  }
  public function last_name() {
    return $this->details()['last_name'];
  }
  public function full_name() {
    return $this->first_name() . ' ' . $this->last_name();
  }
}

$customer = ['details' => ['first_name' => 'N', 'last_name' => 'K']];
$c = new Customer($customer);
echo $c->full_name(); //=> 'N K'
```

This might seem like a lot of work, but that's only because your `$customer` data is so complicated. If your customer data was flat, you'd still want to use data abstraction, but you could do so in a much more simple way …

```
class Customer {
  private $data;
  public function __construct(array $data) {
    $this->data = $data;
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->data) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
  }
  public function full_name() {
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
  }
}

// flat data
$customer = ['first_name' => 'N', 'last_name' => 'K'];
$c = new Customer($customer);
echo $c->full_name(); //=> 'N K'
```